# React Native Push Notification Not Working After Kill And Re-run App

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have implemented Firebase Push Notifications for my project and Once I do register and do the payment back end will fire push notification for me.

For the first time, the app is installed, and create an account and do payment It will work fine.

But once I kill the app from running apps and reopen it then there will be no notification.

I have created separate class for FCM service and here the code

```
import {Linking, Platform} from 'react-native';
import navigationService from '../navigation/navigationService';
import {fcmService} from './FCMServiceHelper';
import {localNotificationService} from './NotificationHelper';
import {saveFCMToken} from './tokenUtils';

export default class NotificationHandler {
  enableDevicePushNotifications = () => {
    fcmService.registerAppWithFCM();
    fcmService.register(onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotificaion);

    function onRegister(token) {
      saveFCMToken(token);
    }

    if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
      localNotificationService.createChannelAndroid('wapp');
    }

    function onNotification(notify) {
      var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      const options = {
        soundName: 'default',
        playSound: true,
      };
      localNotificationService.showNotification(
        RandomNumber,
        notify.title,
        Platform.OS == 'android' ? notify.body : notify.body,
        notify,
        options,
        'wapp',
      );
    }
    function onOpenNotificaion(notify) {
      console.log(' ~ FCM LOG', notify);

    }
    

  };
}
```

On My app, main file everytime the app opens I call this function like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    checkNotifications().then(({status, settings}) => {
      if (status == 'granted' && user?.login?.isLoggedIn == true) {
        let notificationHandler = new NotificationHandler();
        notificationHandler.enableDevicePushNotifications();
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

This is the firebase config helper file

```
/* 
Firebase Helper File for Push Notifications
*/
import {AppState, Platform} from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import * as TokenUtils from './tokenUtils';
import {device} from '../utils/uiUtils';
let deviceToken = null;

class FCMServiceHelper {
  register = (onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotification) => {
    this.checkDeviceToken();
    this.checkPermission(onRegister);
    this.createNotificationListeners(
      onRegister,
      onNotification,
      onOpenNotification,
    );
  };

  checkDeviceToken = async () => {
    let async_fcmToken = await TokenUtils.getFCMToken();
    if (async_fcmToken !== null) {
      deviceToken = async_fcmToken;
    }
  };

  registerAppWithFCM = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
      await messaging().setAutoInitEnabled(true);
    }
  };

  checkPermission = (onRegister) => {
    messaging()
      .hasPermission()
      .then((enabled) => {
        if (enabled) {
          // User has permissions
          this.getToken(onRegister);
        } else {
          // User doesn't have permission
          this.requestPermission(onRegister);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('[FCMService] Permission rejected ', error);
      });
  };

  getToken = (onRegister) => {
    messaging()
      .getToken()
      .then((fcmToken) => {
        if (fcmToken) {
          if (deviceToken == null) {
            onRegister(fcmToken);
          } else {
            onRegister(deviceToken);
          }
        } else {
          console.log('[FCMService] User does not have a device token');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('[FCMService] getToken rejected ', error);
      });
  };

  requestPermission = (onRegister) => {
    messaging()
      .requestPermission()
      .then(() => {
        this.getToken(onRegister);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('[FCMService] Request Permission rejected ', error);
      });
  };

  deleteToken = () => {
    console.log('[FCMService] deleteToken ');
    messaging()
      .deleteToken()
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('[FCMService] Delete token error ', error);
      });
  };

  createNotificationListeners = (
    onRegister,
    onNotification,
    onOpenNotification,
  ) => {
    // When the application is running, but in the background
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp((remoteMessage) => {
      console.log(
        '[FCMService] onNotificationOpenedApp Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage,
      );
      if (remoteMessage) {
        const notification = remoteMessage.notification;
        // onOpenNotification(notification);
        // this.removeDeliveredNotification(notification.notificationId)
      }
    });

    // When the application is opened from a quit state.
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then((remoteMessage) => {
        console.log(
          '[FCMService] getInitialNotification Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
          remoteMessage,
        );

        if (remoteMessage) {
          const notification = remoteMessage.notification;
          onOpenNotification(notification);
          //  this.removeDeliveredNotification(notification.notificationId)
        }
      });

    // Foreground state messages
    this.messageListener = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log(
        '[FCMService] A new FCM message arrived! foreground',
        remoteMessage,
      );
      if (remoteMessage) {
        let notification = null;
        let data = remoteMessage.data;

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          notification = remoteMessage.notification;
          // if (AppState == 'background') {
          //   onOpenNotification(notification);
          // }
        } else {
          notification = remoteMessage.notification;
        }
        notification.data = data;
        onNotification(notification);

        // if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
        //   onOpenNotification(notification);
        // }
      }
    });
    // Triggered when have new token
    messaging().onTokenRefresh((fcmToken) => {
      alert('REFRESH TOKEN');
      console.log('[FCMService] New token refresh: ', fcmToken);
      onRegister(fcmToken);
    });
  };

  unRegister = () => {
    this.messageListener();
  };
}

export const fcmService = new FCMServiceHelper();
```

But notification comes only with initial app loading. after kill and re-run, there is no any notifications